# How to create a cart model in prisma in relation with user and product models?

Tags: api, e-commerce, cart, prisma

I have a `product` and `user` model in `schema.prisma`.

```
type Photo {
  height Int
  width  Int
  url    String
}

model User {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email      String    @unique
  password   String
  products   Product[]
  role       Role
  profileImg Photo
}


model Product {
  id            String            @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String
  price         Int
  stock         Int
  createdAt     DateTime          @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime          @updatedAt
  user          User              @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String            @db.ObjectId
  brand         String
}
```

Now, I want to make a cart model which will have two fields one for the user and another for cartItems. Its type should be like

```
type cartItems = {product: Product, quantity: number}[]
```

Now how do I create the cart model for this. since I can't write like this

```
type CartItem {
  product: Product
  quantity: Int
}

model Cart {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId    String     @db.ObjectId
  user      User       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  cartItems CartItem[]
}
```

because composite type can't have relations.
One way I can do it, is by changing CartItem type to this

```
type cartItem {
  productId  String @db.ObjectId
  quantity Int
}
```

But, in this case, for getting products in cart items, a separate request need to be made with the productId.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation (funnily I used the exact same names for everything). What did you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

maybe Many-to-many relation Order(Cart) <-> Product with quantity field?

```js
model ProductOnOrder {
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  order   Order @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
  orderId String // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  quantity Int
  @@id([productId, orderId])
}
```

Then you can set a connection between product and order(cart) with quantity.

```js
function getOrders() {
  return [
    {
      id: 'order-id',
      products: [
        {
          id: 'product-1-id',
          quantity: 3,
        },
        {
          id: 'product-2-id',
          quantity: 6,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

async function seed() {
  await Promise.all(
    getProducts().map((product) => {
      return db.product.create({ data: product });
    }),
  );
  await Promise.all(
    getOrders().map(({ products, ...orderData }) => {
      return db.order.create({
        data: {
          ...orderData,
          products: {
            create: products.map((product) => {
              return {
                product: { connect: { id: product.id } },
                quantity: product.quantity,
              };
            }),
          },
        },
      });
    }),
  );
}

seed();
```